# Printing a Generic data type in Java gives java.lang.Object@46093a82 despite its type

Tags: java, spring-boot, generics, types

I have this simple post request:

```
@PostMapping
public <T> void create(T data) {
    System.out.println(data);
}
```

Whenever I call this request (providing any data type in the form-data like a string or a number), it prints this in the console:

```
java.lang.Object@46093a82
```

it doesn't give any error, just printing this object instead of "name" for example.

What's the problem?

Comment: Where does `@PostMapping` come from? Also unless objects implement `toString`, they print like this.

Comment: and that must be an instance of `java.lang.Object` as is being printed (if that instances `toString` is not *mocking* an `Object`)

Comment: can u please explain more? what do you mean by where does @PostMapping come from? and can you please further clarify the second part of your comment? how can I apply this in my code?

Comment: please explain more I'm not getting your point

Comment: `@PostMapping` is not standard java, so you are using some framework. What is it, what version? How are you calling this method, where does `data` come from?

Comment: I'm using springboot, and Im calling this request using postman, I send data in form-data

Comment: Your code calls `System.out.println(data)` where `data` is defined as `T`. It looks like `T` in your sample is an instance of `java.lang.Object` (because it printed that out). If you're expecting `data` to be something else (for example, a string), then somehow that type information didn't make it.

Comment: I don't know springboot or how it handles arbitrary generic method types. With known types, examples show a `@RequestBody String body` as the method argument. Example: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring5/webmvc/controller-getmapping-postmapping/#3-spring-postmapping-example

Comment: @markspace, I disagree.  I believe the default implementation of toString uses the actual runtime type of the object, so I think this is genuinely a java.lang.Object.

Comment: OK I see what you're saying.  The default method access the runtime type when it prints out, not just some static string.  It's really weird that an Object is floating around in the system, something seems off there. @LouisWasserman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`java.lang.Object@46093a82` is printed, because that's what needs to be printed.
All Java objects have a toString() method (this method is defined in the Object class), which is invoked when you try to print the object.
The Object.toString() method returns a string, composed of the name of the class, an @ symbol and the hashcode of the object in hexadecimal.
To print something different when you call System.out.println(Object), you must override the toString() method in your own class.
simple example:

```
 public class Foo {

  private String name;

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return name;
  }
}
```